# style.setProperty does not render

Tags: javascript, css

It seems like using this function would be more portable or reliable, because the alternative is to set an attribute:

```
element.style.setProperty(styleproperty, valuestring);
element.setAttribute('style',styleproperty+': '+valuestring+';');
```

The second method would also seem slightly more inefficient though that's hardly a concern.

But at least on Chrome, the style does not update on the page unless I use the `setAttribute` method.

The reason why this is a bit of an issue, is that I have potentially many different separate style properties I want to modify independently of the others. I have to do a whole lot of string parsing and processing if I can't make use of `setProperty`, `removeProperty`, etc. I have to pull out the style string, search it, modify it, and set it back in via `setAttribute`. Should work, but I don't like it.

Is there a reason for this? Is this a bug? My guess is that `setAttribute` triggers something for the browser to perform a re-render. What is a suitable way to force this update that is generally browser-friendly?

Comment: These are all inline styles you wish to modify? [This page at quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting the `style` attribute directly has consequences that may be undesirable: it will wipe out all existing styles set in the element's `style` attribute, and `setAttribute` is broken in older IE (and compatibility modes in later IE). Much safer is to use the element's `style` property directly to set only the style property you need:

```
element.style[styleproperty] = valuestring;
```

This will update the page immediately in all major browsers.

One caveat: CSS style properties (generally using dashes, such as in `background-color`) do not map precisely to properties of the DOM element's `style` object (generally camel case, such as in `backgroundColor`). There are also exceptions to this rule.

Comment: Okay I seem to have overlooked the possibility of doing it this way. If it does update and render that will solve my problems!

Comment: @Steven: I guarantee it will re-render the relevant bits of the page. If it doesn't, your code has other problems :)

Comment: It does! Though if the value string has a semicolon it doesn't work. Also was surprised to find out that `element.style['background-color']` works even though it should be `backgroundColor`.

Comment: @StevenLu: That's interesting but non-standard. A quick test suggests that `element.style['background-color']` works in Chrome but not Firefox, so probably best not to rely on that.

Comment: Anyone know how to set the value to "!important"? Need to override someone's selfish code

Comment: @StuartDobson: Setting a style property using the element's `style` object will override everything, including `!important` rules.

Comment: @StuartDobson: using `style.setProperty(name, val, important)` -- the 3rd arg. is actually mandatory, if I'm correct.

Comment: We lose the ability to set important if we use element.style[stylePropery] syntax

Comment: @Pavan: That's true.